# How is ozone formation form oxygen **spontaneous**?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

[image]
DeltaH for process is positive and deltaS is negative. Then by thermodynamics,deltaG for process must be positive at all temperatures. Then how is ozone formation spontaneous?

Comment: Why do you think it is spontaneous.

Comment: '...a slow dry stream of oxygen is passed through an [electrical] discharge...'   (the picture cut off at the end of the line).   If an electrical current is required then the process isn't spontaneous at all, you're putting energy in

Comment: Do you regularly notice oxygen in the air spontaneously converting into ozone?

Comment: How long would it take you to either type out the contents of the text in your image or re-image it so the rest of us can see it?  I will then probably spend at least that much time working towards an answer for you.  I cannot promise that I will come up with an answer good enough for posting, but I'll try ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems reasonable to suspect that some O<sub>2</sub> molecules will dissociate in the discharge. Some of the resulting atoms will bond to other O<sub>2</sub> to form O<sub>3</sub> instead of recombining. To evaluate the thermodynamics of this process, one should therefore start at atomic oxygen.